# Location is null when gps is on

Tags: android

I am getting current location,if gps is on then location from gps provider or else from network provider.Network provider returns current location but gps provider always returns null location.How to fix this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674414/location-returned-is-null-when-provider-is-gps?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: it takes some time to lock on

Comment: try this example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: thanks finally i got output @AndroidDeveloper

Comment: its my pleasure miss. and next time first search for query before post question here .you get down vote because of you didn’t explain proper and also not search for this.anyway are you student?

Answer (score 0):

- if you are using device with android OS 6.0.1, GPS location provider
  requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission for android 6.0 in
  menifest.xml.

Since 6.0 some permissions are considered as "dangerous" (FINE_LOCATION is one of them).

To protect the user, they have to be authorized at runtime, so the user know if it's related to his action.
You can check complete example on below link:
https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-marshmallow-permissions.html